# SQL Server: How to report error from a job's step of PowerShell type

Tags: powershell, sql

I have a SQL job whose step of 'PowerShell' type does 'exit 1' if encounters an error i.e.

$ErrorActionPreference='stop'; trap{"$_"; exit 1}

Problem is, SQL Server doesn't pay attention to that exit code, and reports "The step did not generate any output.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded."

Any idea how to successfully tell SQL Server from a PowerShell step that something went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

throw "Failure" will work. See [this MSDN forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/d511fce9-fa79-4f92-bc44-72d6d562930a/#9beea9fc-337f-4af5-94e6-c5ea81b2c92b) for additional information: